# Determine if Android device supports BLE 5

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Obviously you can mark your app as needing the BLE permissions to run and you can check if the device supports BLE in general, but is there a way to check whether or not the platform supports BLE 5 in particular?

Comment: Is there a particular feature in Bluetooth 5 you want to check for?

Comment: @Emil Largely, we want make use of the larger advertisement message size. I'm assuming that android would handle it opaquely and just give us a scan record containing our data if the android device supported BLE 5. However, what would happen if the device does not? I suspect that the data gets truncated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is flatly that [Android 8.0+ supports BLE 5](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising).